# Strange behaviour in C++ when comparing 2 values with "or" and "?" operator

Tags: c++, initialization, conditional-operator, comparison-operators, logical-or

I have some code in an old desktop app, which I inheritted from a colegue who left the company.
Here is a short similar example of the actual code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
int getType(int type)
{
    return type;
}

int main()
{
    int variable1 = 30;
    int variable2 = 40;
    int result = (getType(30) == (variable1 || variable2) ? 1 : 2);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

For the result I always receive 2, not 1 as I expected.
If I try:

`int result = (getType(30) == (variable1) ? 1 : 2)`

the result is true.

I can't figure out why this part:

`int result = (getType(30) == (variable1 || variable2) ? 1 : 2)`

is not true...

Comment: That's not how comparing multiple variables with a value works. You want `(getType(30) == variable1) || (getType(30) ==  variable2)`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922943/how-to-check-if-variable-equal-to-multiple-values) is a C question but it happens to be a case where the same thing applies to both C and C++. There may be a canonical C++ version of this question.

Comment: you must learn operator precedence first and you can solve such doubts yourself. Happy learning :)

Comment: @NaseebPanghal - nothing to do with operator precedence

Comment: You seem to be unaware that `(30 || 40)` just means `true`.  Or `1` in your case, since you are comparing it to an `int`.  Your expression is the same as `getType(30) == 1 ? 1 : 2`

Answer (score 5):

In the initializer expression of this declaration

```
int result = (getType(30) == (variable1 || variable2) ? 1 : 2);
```

the subexpression `(variable1 || variable2)` has the type `bool` and its value is `true` (`variable1` isn't 0 so that is true) that is implicitly converted to the integer value `1` in the expression with the equality operator `(getType(30) == (variable1 || variable2)` .

From the C++17 Standard (7.6 Integral promotions)

> 6 A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int,
> with false becoming zero and true becoming one.

So as `getType(30)` is not equal to `1` the result of the initializer expression is `2`.

To get the expected result you should rewrite the declaration like

```
int result = (getType(30) == variable1 || getType(30) == variable2) ? 1 : 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps your understanding of the `||` operator is not quite right. The `||` operator is the or operator, and it will return a boolean result, `false` or `true`. In your code, you are doing this comparison: `getType(30) == (variable1 || variable2)`. The parenthesis get evaluated first because of order of operations and you end up with `getType(30) == true`, since `variable1` has a non-zero value. `getType(30)` evaluates and returns `30`, so the expression is `30 == true`. The `true` value then gets coerced to a `1` because of the rules of c++ and we evalate `30 == 1` which is `false`.

I think what you are asking for is why this doesn't do what you expect. And I see two problems, the one is that the `getType` function doesn't actually do what you might expect, it simply returns the variable. I'm not sure what you would expect in c++, but that's definitely a problem. The other expectation is probably that you want to compare the return of `getType(30)` with both `variable1` and `variable2` which would require a longer expression. The expression you want is probably `getType(30) == variable1 || getType(30) == variable2`. This is a common problem because in english we say 'if gettype equals var1 or var2`, but it doesn't translate into code like that unfortunately.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `(variable1 || variable2)` is either `false` or `true`, not `0` or `1`. And for these particular values, `(variable1 || variable2)` is `true`, not `false`.  But when `true` gets promoted for the comparison with `30`, it gets promoted to `1`, and `30 == 1` is still `false`.

Comment: Right, thank you, lemme go fix that quickly.