# How to check if a variable is equal to multiple variables

Tags: c, cs50, logical-operators

I am currently taking the "CS50 Introduction To Computer Science" course, and I'm still quite new to programming in C. I'm working on a simple agreement project that involves using if statements. However, as a beginner, I'm facing some difficulties with my code.

If there's anyone experienced with C programming who could lend a helping hand, I would be incredibly grateful for your assistance. Below is the code that I've attempted so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string username = get_string("What would you like your username to be? ");
    string agreement = get_string("Do you agree to the following terms & conditions? ");
    if (!strcmp(agreement, "yes" || agreement, "y" || agreement, "Yes" || agreement, "Y"))
    {
        printf("You can now continue using the service, %s! \n", username);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(agreement, "no" || agreement, "n" || agreement, "Yes" || agreement, "Y"))
    {
        printf("You need to agree to the terms & conditions to use the service\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You need to select a option\n");
    }
}
```

And here is the error that is thrown when I try to compile the code:

```
Too many arguments for function call. Expected 2, Have 5
```

I tried to search similar questions on google and found this result: [How to check if variable equal to multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922943/how-to-check-if-variable-equal-to-multiple-values)
But, I couldn't solve my problem. Here is the code that I tried (which did not work):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string username = get_string("What would you like your username to be? ");
    string agreement = get_string("Do you agree to the following terms & conditions? ");
    if (str[agreement] == 'yes' || str[agreement] == 'y' || str[agreement] == 'Yes' || str[agreement] == 'Y')
    {
        printf("You can now continue using the service %s! \n", usename);
    }
    else if (str[agreement] == 'no' || str[agreement] == 'n' || str[agreement] == 'No' || str[agreement] == 'N')
    {
        printf("You need to agree to the terms & conditions to use the service\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You need to select a option\n");
    }
}
```

But I received this error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier "str"
```

I'm excided to learn and appreciate any guidance or tips you can provide to help me make progress on this project. Thank you so much for your time and support!

Comment: The only way to compare strings in C is to a function such as `strcmp`. To compare multiple strings, you will need to apply the function on each one of the strings.  There is no way around it. Well, you could implement a fancy algorithm with prefix trees and such, but you probably don't want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcmp` takes two aruments. As written in you first example, you are passing a bunch of non-sense into it.

Instead, make *multiple* strcmp checks, and "or" their results:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string username = get_string("What would you like your username to be? ");
    string agreement = get_string("Do you agree to the following terms & conditions? ");
    if (!strcmp(agreement, "yes") || !strcmp(agreement, "y") || !strcmp(agreement, "Yes") || !strcmp(agreement, "Y"))
    {
        printf("You can now continue using the service, %s! \n", username);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(agreement, "no") || !strcmp(agreement, "n") || !strcmp(agreement, "Yes") || !strcmp(agreement, "Y"))
    {
        printf("You need to agree to the terms & conditions to use the service\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You need to select a option\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `strcmp()` returns **zero** if the strings match....

Comment: And you need to fix your cut-and-paste job...

Comment: Eventually use strcasecmp() to match both upper and lowercase in a single call.

Answer (score 2):

So, the error is because of this line:

```
if (!strcmp(agreement, "yes" || agreement, "y" || agreement, "Yes" || agreement, "Y"))
```

That call to `strcmp` is being *parsed* as

```
strcmp(agreement, ("yes" || agreement), ("y" || agreement), ("Yes || agreement), "Y")
```

hence the "too many arguments" error.  That *should* be written as

```
if (!strcmp(agreement, "yes") ||  // you're comparing the results
    !strcmp(agreement, "y")   ||  // of four separate calls to
    !strcmp(agreement, "Yes") ||  // strcmp
    !strcmp(agreement, "Y") )
{
  ...
}
```

Since it looks like you only care about the first letter of `agreement`, you can simplify that a bit:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
if ( tolower( agreement[0] ) == 'y' ) // convert the first letter of
{                                     // agreement to lower case and
  ...                                 // compare against 'y'
}
else if ( tolower( agreement[0] ) == 'n' )
{
  ...
}
else
{
  ...
}
```

This will work if `agreement` contains any of the strings `"Yes"`, `"yes"`, `"Y"`, `"y"`, `"YO, ADRIAN!"`, `"yup"`, etc.

Be aware, CS50 *grossly* misrepresents string operations in C.  C does not have an actual `string` data type; that's unique to the CS50 library.  It's an alias for the type `char *` (pointer to `char`).  The `get_string` function allocates memory to store the string behind the scenes and returns a pointer to that memory, which is what actually gets stored in `agreement`:

```
           +---+          +---+
agreement: |   | -------> |'Y'|  
           +---+          +---+
                          |'e'|
                          +---+
                          |'s'|
                          +---+
                          | 0 |
                          +---+
```

In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values including a zero-valued terminator.  The string `"yes"` is represented as the sequence `{'y', 'e', 's', 0}`.

Strings are *stored* in arrays of character type.  You can *initialize* an array with a string in a declaration:

```
 char greeting[SIZE] = "hello";
```

or

```
 char greeting[SIZE] = {'h', 'e', 'l',  'l', 'o', 0};
```

but you cannot *assign* arrays to each other using the `=` operator; this won't work:

```
 greeting = "goodbye";
```

You either have to use a library function like `strcpy`:

```
strcpy( greeting, "goodbye" );
```

or assign each element individually:

```
greeting[0] = 'g';
greeting[1] = 'o';
greeting[2] = 'o';
...
greeting[6] = 'e';
greeting[7] = 0;
```

Similarly, you can't use `==` to compare array contents, you must use a library function like `strcmp` or `memcmp`, or compare elements individually.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explenation but, If I'm not mistaken CS50 is only a 101 / Introduction to CS. So it shouldn't be taken as a C course right?